# HashTable Implementation Get and Set Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a ***basic*** hashtable. I'm using a linked list to resolve collisions.

My **get** and **set** methods are giving me a bunch of trouble, and I'm not really sure what the issue is. I believe I'm overloading the operators correctly. I think the problem happens when I append to my linked list.

```
class HashTable {
  struct Node{
    int key;
    int value;
    Node *next;
  };
  Node **table;
  int hash_func(int key) const {
    return key % TABLE_SIZE;
  }
public:
  HashTable() {
    table = new Node*[TABLE_SIZE]();
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
      table[i] = nullptr;
  }

  int& operator[](int const key) {
    int h_key = hash_func(key);

    while(table[h_key]) {
      table[h_key] = table[h_key]->next;
    }

    table[h_key] = new Node;
    table[h_key]->key = key;
    table[h_key]->next = table[h_key];

    return table[h_key]->value;
  }

  int operator[](int const key) const {
    int h_key = hash_func(key);

    while (table[h_key]) {
      if (table[h_key]->key == key) {
        return table[h_key]->value;
      }
      table[h_key] = table[h_key]->next;
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: Rule of 3 stands out immediately.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I have a destructor and friends, I was just highlighting a small part giving me issues.

Comment: @clo_jur You tagged this as `C++11` -- I don't see any C++11 features being used in your code at all.  It doesn't even use C++98 features (not even `std::list` even though you mentioned "linked list").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are *overwriting* data in your `while` loops in your get and set methods.

When you do `table[h_key] = table[h_key]->next;`, you *permanently lose* whatever was originally stored at location `h_key`. Instead **use a placeholder**, like this:

```
Node * curr = table[h_key];
while (curr->next)
{
  curr =  curr->next;
}

Node * new_node = new Node;
new_node->key = key;
curr->next = new_node;
```

You have a similar problem with your get method.

Answer (score 2):

In your setter, you want to insert a new element at the end. So first you find the end like this:

```
while(table[h_key]) {
  table[h_key] = table[h_key]->next;
}
```

But then, you set:

```
table[h_key]->next = table[h_key];
```

Instead, you would have to set:

```
table[h_key]->next = nullptr;
```

Otherwise, your condition in the loop does not work.

Consider this answer to an addendum to @bpachev's answer. My code only illustrates the problem using your wrong code, and is not a drop-in solution.

Comment: hmm... I was actually trying to set it at the beginning and just attach the new node to the beginning of the list.

Comment: That makes more sense than attaching it at the end precisely because you wouldn't have to loop to the end of the list... Realize something? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bpachev. Since this is C++, you should consider using templates for something like this (to removing clutter and reuse). Overhead for using template classes are minimal, and this process is done during compile time.